# How to get error message from response body when use Alamofire.download() request

Tags: swift, download, alamofire, response, message

```swift
AF.download(url, parameters: params, to: destination)
  .validate(statusCode: [200])
  .response { response in
    switch response.result {
    case .success(let url):
      print("ok", url)
    case .failure(let err):
      print(err.localizedDescription)
    }
  }
```

When server response some error code like 4xx, 5xx, it will print "Response status code was unacceptable: xxx.", but I want the detail message in response body(server send plain text when error), I read some post that said we can retrieve response message with "response.data" but if use AF.download method, there isn't have "data" property with response object(Alamofire.AFDownloadResponse). so, is there any way to figure it out?

Comment: Maybe `response.resumeData`?

Comment: No, response.resumeData is nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alamofire's `DownloadResponse` contains a `fileURL: URL?` property which can be used to load the downloaded data from disk even when validation or other actions produce a failure result in the response.

Comment: Although this is a bit strange (save response to file regardless of whether status succeed or not), but it really does get the server return message. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: That's what a download is: a direct download to disk of the data returned by the server. Alamofire *could* support the dynamic data task to download task conversion, but that's highly complex just to prevent a single disk read.

Answer (score 0):

This is from Alamofire Source Code;

> The debug textual representation used when written to an output stream, which includes (if available) a summary of the `URLRequest`, the request's headers and body (if decodable as a `String` below 100KB); the `HTTPURLResponse`'s status code, headers, and body; the duration of the network and serialization actions; and the `Result` of serialization.

Response debug description has status code information. So, the response should have status code information.

Also when I check source code, I see this part;

```
static func description(of response: HTTPURLResponse) -> String {
    """
    [Response]:
        [Status Code]: \(response.statusCode)
        \(DebugDescription.description(for: response.headers).indentingNewlines())
    """
}
```

So, **response.status** should give what your want. Good luck.

Comment: I need not only a status code, but also a server returned description, anyway thank you for your answer.